# Insert values which are taken from the for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, python-3.x

In this code I have printed these n values separately.But I want these values to be printed in a single array after each looping.How can I do that?

```
n=1000000
for x in range(1,3000001):
    if n%2==0:
        x=n/2
    else:
        x=3*n+ 1
    n=x
    print(n)
    if n==1:
        break
```

Thank you.

Comment: refer [Collatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)

Answer (score 4):

Use `end=' '` inside `print()`:

```
print(n, end=' ')
```

**Demo:**

```
for i, x in enumerate(range(10), 1):
    print (x, end=' ')
    if x==5:
        break
...         
0 1 2 3 4 5
>>> print(i)  #print the count
6
```

Comment: Then how can I count the number of elements in that array?

Comment: @user2297793 You can use `enumerate` to keep a track of total items traversed so far, see my updated solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could store the values in a list, (such as `result` below):

```
n = 1000000
result = [] 
for x in range(1, 3000001):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        x = n / 2
    else:
        x = 3 * n + 1
    n = x
    result.append(n)
    if n == 1:
        break
print(result)
# [500000, 250000, 125000,... 8, 4, 2, 1]
print(len(result))
# 152
```

Storing the items in a list gives you the opportunity to further process those items later in the code. You can print them, count them, do more computation on them, etc.

However, it does require memory to store them all, so if you don't need to retain them all in memory at the same time, Ashwini Chaudhary's solution would be better.

Here is an approach similar to Ashwini's, except that it separates the printing from the computation. This is always a good thing since often one wishes to perform a computation and not display results at the same time.

```
n = 1000001

def myseq(n):
    for x in range(1, 3000001):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            x = n / 2
        else:
            x = 3 * n + 1
        n = x
        yield n
        if n == 1:
            return

for n, item in enumerate(myseq(n), 1):
    print(n, end=' ')
# 500000 250000 125000... 8 4 2 1
print('\n{}'.format(n))
```